# Restoration of Jesus fresco a fake?

Tags: art, spain

[The story goes](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/amateur-turns-church-fresco-of-jesus-into-hairy-monkey-in-botched-restoration/article4494768/):

> A devout Spanish woman is being roundly criticized after taking it
>   upon herself to restore a church fresco of Jesus, a ham-fisted attempt
>   that left the piece looking like a child’s daubing.

Here is the end result:

[image]

It cracks me up every time I look at it, but the story seems like a fake. The thing that I think gives it away are the images of the two paintings side-by-side.

So is there any truth in this story?

There appears to be no evidence of the original painting aside from the image being circulated.

Comment: Excellent question. I've failed to find much corroborating evidence; not speaking Spanish is a hindrance. What I have found, for anyone trying to do better: there is an area 67kms from [Zaragoza/Saragossa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaragoza) called *Santuario de la Misericordia*, which translates as "Sanctuary of Mercy", so I'm guessing that is where the church is. Some sources have the fresco called "Ecco Homo", but they probably mean "[Ecce Homo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecce_Homo)". I couldn't find the official quoted.

Comment: Ah, [this has a summary](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/events/botched-ecce-homo-painting) including [interview footage from the Telegraph](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuPuVEPgtjc). If it is a fake news story, it is a high quality one.

Comment: @Oddthinking - Seems to have hit the [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/24/world/europe/botched-restoration-of-ecce-homo-fresco-shocks-spain.html) and is now trending on Google News as well.

Comment: @Rob, it is a huge viral story, but the papers are all just quoting each other. The Telegraph interview is a first-hand report.

Comment: @Oddthinking - I've searched extensively and I believe that the church exists, but I can't find any information about the original work or an original in situ photograph. There are some photos of the place on Flickr, but I can't spot the painting in any of them and there are no pre-2011 Google results that mention the painting when combined with the location. Seems fishy to me. Noticed some dude has already added the painting to 'Ecce Homo' Wikipedia.

Comment: If the latter painting is a fake, then I guess there's two possibilities: someone photographed or created a real life dilapidated version, and created a real life botched version, or someone used photoshop. I suspect the latter would be the easier option, and be detectable.

Comment: The story is true, but exaggerate. Such a big repercusion was never expected. The fresco is an uncatalogued piece of minor art in a small church of a small village. Try to translate [this](http://cesbor.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/el-impacto-de-una-noticia-local.html) article. It comes from a local group and shows that their blog is overwhelmed with thousand of dayly visits, when they normally had 500 visits a day. In a previous entry they claim to have published an article about the fresco two years before the "restoration".

Comment: Keep in mind, that it's just fresco done by local painter in local church, Elías García Martínez didn't even have entry in **Spanish** wikipedia until yesterday. And only other mention of the author is in museum in Requena, town of 21.000 people.

Comment: Where you searching the Spanish language sources? Google does tend to have some selection bias towards the current regional setting.

Comment: @RobZ: I do have Spanish as one of my preferred languages in Google settings ;-)

Answer (score 30):

Yes, it's real.

It has been extensively covered by Spanish national TV (TVE) and newspapers (mainstream, not tabloids).

- ["La restauración que se convirtió en destrozo" (Restoration becomes a disaster)](http://cultura.elpais.com/cultura/2012/08/21/actualidad/1345563468_581914.html) — one of numerous articles in [El País](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Pa%C3%ADs), mainstream daily, biggest in Spain
- ["Expertos intentarán restaurar el Ecce Homo "destrozado" por una anciana" (Experts to attempt restore the Ecce Homo "destroyed" by an elderly)](http://www.rtve.es/noticias/20120822/expertos-intentaran-restaurar-ecce-homo-destrozado-anciana/559321.shtml) — one of numerous reports in [TVE, Spanish National TV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Televisi%C3%B3n_Espa%C3%B1ola).

The news originates from [Centro de Estudios Borjanos](http://cesbor.blogspot.com.es/) (Study Center of [Borja](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borja,_Aragon)). It has been originally reported on [their blog on 7th of August](http://cesbor.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/un-hecho-incalificable.html).

15 days later it has been [picked up](http://www.heraldo.es/noticias/cultura/2012/08/21/la_restauracion_una_pintura_mural_una_iglesia_borja_acaba_chapuza_200865_308.html) by regional newspaper [*Heraldo de Aragón*](http://www.heraldo.es/). From there it made national news and went viral internationally.

The painting itself has been [mentioned 2 years ago](http://cesbor.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/un-articulo-publicado-hace-dos-anos.html) in one of Centro de Estudios Borjanos information bulletins (*Boletín Informativo nº 129-130* of 2010)

[image: Borja]

---

Keep in mind, that it is not priceless art masterpiece, as some international news suggest. It's been painted by local painter in local church. Elías García Martínez [didn't even have entry in Spanish wikipedia until yesterday](http://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=El%C3%ADas_Garc%C3%ADa_Mart%C3%ADnez&action=history). And only other mention of the author is in museum in [Requena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requena,_Valencia), town of 21.000 people.

Above bulletin doesn't mention exact date when it was painted, but gives some hints as author lived in region of Zaragoza in 1894-1934. The painting is a copy of engraving by William Trench, which itself is a copy of medieval painting by [Guido Reni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_Reni). The painting is a mural, but it is **not fresco**. It's painted with oil paint.

Comment: Any idea about the authenticity of the information bulletins? How are they typically available? Can we access them from the source?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: Centro de Estudios Borjanos is the source. Again, it's a local center in rather small town, 5K population. Which has been caught quite by surprise with all the international interest.

Comment: I seem to recall reading some where this is not even a particularly old(by art standards) fresco but rather one which was done in the 1900's in the style of the old masters.

Comment: @Chad: right, copy of a copy. Added that info.

Comment: @Vartec - I think it may have been a fresco.  A fresco is a painting done on wet plaster.

Comment: @Chad: right, fresco is done over fresh plaster with water soluble paint. The bulletin explicitly states that it's a "small oil painting"

Comment: Good job, @vartec!

Comment: @Sklivvz: thanks, given Spanish sources wasn't too hard though.